# how can split data into 2 partition from the peak in the density graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2, erp, rlang

i can get the peak on the graph and can draw line on it 
but now i need to split my data to 2 parts ( before the peak) and (after the peak)

how can do that ?

this is the code which i used to get a peak and draw line on it :

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(DS, aes(DS$loan_amount_ink)) + geom_density()


Ymax <- which.max(density( DS$loan_amount_ink)$y)  

Xmax <- density(DS$loan_amount_ink)$x[Ymax]       


ggplot(DS, aes(DS$loan_amount_ink)) + geom_density() + 
       geom_vline(xintercept = density( DS$loan_amount_ink)$x[Ymax])
```

Comment: Do you need to split the raw data or do you need to split the plot density graph at the point of Xmax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
View(faithful)
ggplot(faithful, aes(waiting)) + geom_density()
```

[image]

```
which.max(density(faithful$waiting)$y) # Peak
peak <- density(faithful$waiting)$x[326]
peak # 79.96245
ggplot(faithful, aes(waiting)) + 
  geom_density() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = density(faithful$waiting)$x[326])
```

[image]

Dividing the dataset according to the peak density.

```
df1 <- faithful %>% 
  dplyr::filter(waiting <= peak)

df2 <- faithful %>% 
  dplyr::filter(waiting > peak)
```

Source - find peak density: http://ianmadd.github.io/pages/PeakDensityDistribution.html